Command to get the complete dump from MQ version below 7.5
We are having a requirement to upgrade MQv 7.x to MQv 9x. we could able to get the dump for the MQ V 7.5 using below commands
dmpmqcfg -m QueueManagerName -t all -o mqsc
dmpmqcfg -m QueueManagerName -t qmgr -a > /tmp/File
Could you please anyone help with the command on how we can get the complete dump from MQ like queues, channel, authrec, listeners etc for the version v7.0.

7.0 didn't have dmpmqcfg, but you can connect as a client from dmpmqcfg on a newer install to the 7.0 queue manager. You can also see if you can find retired SupportPAC MS03 (saveqmgr), I believe this is now on github.

Or you could use MO71 to export all your object definitions. It supports EVERY version of MQ.

@Virat, did the above comments help to resolve your issue?
